# Deriving an equality involving Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, vector-fields

Let

$$\hat{T} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d^dr d^d r' \psi^\dagger (\vec r ) (\int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} |\vec k|^2 e^{i \vec k  \cdot(\vec r - \vec r')})\psi(\vec r')$$

The transform in the middle is $\nabla^2$ at $\vec r - \vec r'$.

$\psi$ has the commutation relation $[\psi(\vec r),\psi^{\dagger}(\vec r')]=\delta^d(\vec r - \vec r')$

I still can't show that
$$\hat{T} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d^dr \nabla\psi^\dagger (\vec r ) \cdot \nabla\psi (\vec r )$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Doing the fourier transform in the middle (Remembering that $\lambda=\frac{h}{p} \to p=\hbar k $ and so $k$ correspond to $\frac{\partial}{\partial r_i}$) evaluating the fourier transform in the middle gives:
$$\int \frac{d^dk}{(2 \pi)^d} |\vec k|^2 e^{i \vec k  \cdot(\vec r - \vec r')}=\nabla^2$$ But as a function of the delta $\vec r-\vec r'$, and I don't know what that means for $\nabla^2$.

In order to get rid of the $d^dr'$ in the integral one can try integration by parts (There is probably a mistake here):

$$\hat{T} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int d^dr d^d r' \psi^\dagger (\vec r ) \nabla^2\psi(\vec r') = 
\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} [\int d^dr  \psi^\dagger (\vec r ) \cdot \nabla \psi(\vec r') - \int d^dr d^d r' \nabla\psi^\dagger (\vec r ) \cdot\nabla\psi(\vec r')]$$

If that is even correct it still does not help.

I'm asking this here because I can't ask on the physics stack exchange site.

Comment: Show what you tried please, and where this question came from: I can’t help you myself, but other people would be able to help you better if they knew what your knowledge is and what you’re used to

Comment: Hi. Are you sure it is $\psi(r')$ at the end of your formula ? It seems more likely to me that it is $\psi(k)$ so that the right most integral is $\Delta \psi(r-r')$ and thus you will have a convolution.

Comment: @Steph I am pretty sure.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but in which classes are this kind of integrals taught?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Quantum Field Theory

Comment: @user192234 Thanks for telling. Looks nasty.

Comment: What do you mean you "cannot ask on the physics stackechange?". In any case, first do the $r'$ integral to get $k^2\tilde{\psi}(k)$ on the right. Do the $k$ integral to get $-\nabla^2\psi(r)$. Integrate by parts to move one $\nabla$